# How to filter a dataframe based on the duplicated values?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, duplicates

I have this df

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2,3,4),
                y = LETTERS[1:6] )
```

The desired output is

```
  x y
1 1 A
2 1 B
3 2 C
4 2 D
```

I tried using the `filter` finction but I haven't got the result I am looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `n()` by group:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0 needed or above
df %>% 
  filter(n() > 1, .by = x)

  x y
1 1 A
2 1 B
3 2 C
4 2 D
```

Or, in `base R`:

```r
subset(df, ave(x, x, FUN = length) > 1)
```

And in `data.table`:

```r
setDT(df)[, if(.N > 1) .SD, x]
```

Answer (score 3):

With base R

```
> subset(df, duplicated(df$x)| duplicated(df$x, fromLast = TRUE))
  x y
1 1 A
2 1 B
3 2 C
```

Answer (score 1):

If we group by a single column, all groups with n() > 1 have "duplicated" values for that column

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    filter(n()>1) %>%
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 × 2
      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 A    
2     1 B    
3     2 C    
4     2 D
```